# DHCP option на коммутаторе Dell PowerConnect 5500

Tags: сеть, dhcp, dell, коммутатор

Имею Dell PowerConnect 5524.

Пишу

```
SW01(config-dhcp)# option 43 hex f104ac1338fa
```

получаю

```
Option code 43 is not a valid HEX string.
```

Странно. На циске принимало. Читаю user guide:

> hex hex-string—Specifies dotted hexadecimal data: Each byte in
>   hexadecimal character strings is two hexadecimal digits. Bytes are
>   separated by a period or colon

Пробую

```
SW01(config-dhcp)# option 
  ip-list              Specify an IP address list.
  POSITIVE INTEGER     Specify the DHCP option code number
SW01(config-dhcp)# option 43 
  ascii                ASCII.
  hex                  Specify Option type as Hexadecimal.
  ip                   Specify Option type as IP address.
SW01(config-dhcp)# option 43 hex 
  WORD                 Specify Option type as Hexadecimal.
SW01(config-dhcp)# option 43 hex f1.04.ac.13.38.fa
Option code 43 is not a valid HEX string.
SW01(config-dhcp)# option 43 hex f1:04:ac:13:38:fa
Option code 43 is not a valid HEX string.
```

Внимание - вопрос! Как мне отдавать option 43 с этого коммутатора?

Спасибо заранее, всем хорошего времяпрепровождения!

Comment: А если использовать `ip` или `ascii` ? `option 43 ip 172.19.56.250` или `option 43 ascii "172.19.56.250"`

Comment: ip адресс переданный в ascii работает для точек 1100 серии, для серии 1600 и 1700 не работает. `SW01(config-dhcp)# option 43 ip 172.19.56.250` результат
`Option code 43 is not a valid IP address.`